# Rendering a shape rather than a point in Graphics

Tags: graphics

Here is some sample data

```
m = {{0.658254, 1.04273, 0.15, 0.613587, 2}, {0.157981, 4.03653, 1.25, 
        0.437706, 1}, {0.149204, 1.65371, 2.72, 0.571777, 1}, {0.495885, 
        3.62412, 1.67, 0.00119993, 3}, {-0.149204, 2.23414, 200., 0.260858, 
        0}, {-0.50905, 2.98259, 200., 0.146681, 0}, {-0.662643, 1.60788, 
        21.77, 0.0305032, 1}, {0.539769, 0.385922, 0.33, 0.450807, 
        2}, {0.157981, 3.77687, 1.04, 0.584416, 1}, {-0.623147, 4.32675, 
        200., 0.173352, 0}};
```

A color code

```
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := Module[{s = m[[i, 5]]}, 
Which[s == -1, White, s == 0, Blue, s == 1, Red, s == 2, Darker[Green],
      s == 3, Cyan]];

data = Table[{PointSize[0.004], getColor[m, i], Point[{m[[i, 1]], 
       m[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}];
```

And finally we plot them

```
S0 = Graphics[data]
```

`Graphics` renders the data using dots with the predefined point size. How can I change the plot markers to small squares instead of dots? Of course, I should be able to control the size of the new plot markers.

**EDIT**

If I use @Andrew S method in a `Show` like

```
P0 = Show[S0, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
     PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 500]
```

then the squares become rectangles.

The output of the `Graphics`

[image]

And then the output of the `Show`

[image]

**EDIT 2**

@m_goldberg:

[Test.nb](http://www.mediafire.com/download/739325d4cyzfiac/Test.nb)

The final plot markers are much bigger than in `Graphics`, while some of them are cut in half at the borders.

Comment: Use a small image of a square, then draw image at the desired x,y positions, with possibly a displacement of -a/2,-a/2 to centralize.

Comment: It's a bit funny, because you are building the `Graphics` yourself and you're not using `ListPlot`. It is a very small step to use `Rectangle` instead of `Point` and I wonder why you haven't just tried that?

Comment: Dont actually know what you mean by "become rectangles". DO you mean that the markers are cropped on the border?

Comment: Oh, sorry, something overlapped on my side.
That's all due to the `AspectRatio` thing.
If you want to go this way, then you have to specify the correct ratio here for the markers.
See my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need `Graphics` (even though for this `ListPlot` will be better), then you can use

```
rectSize = 0.05;
data = Table[
   {
    getColor[m, i],
    Rectangle[{m[[i, 1]] - rectSize, 
      m[[i, 2]] - rectSize}, {m[[i, 1]] + rectSize, 
      m[[i, 2]] + rectSize}]
    },
   {i, 1, Length[m]}
   ];
```

To draw rectangles instead of points:

[image]

Or with `ListPlot`

```
markSize = 0.05;
ListPlot[
 Table[{{m[[i, 1]], m[[i, 2]]}}, {i, 1, Length[m]}],
 PlotMarkers -> Table[
   {Graphics[{getColor[m, i], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}], markSize},
   {i, 1, Length[m]}
   ]
 ]
```

For this:

[image]

**EDIT**:

To fix the ratio problem after "post-rationing" the whole graphics object

```
yR = Max[m[[All, 2]]] - Min[m[[All, 2]]];
xR = Max[m[[All, 1]]] - Min[m[[All, 1]]];
rectSize = 0.05;
data = Table[
   {getColor[m, i], 
    Rectangle[{m[[i, 1]] - rectSize*xR/yR, 
      m[[i, 2]] - rectSize}, {m[[i, 1]] + rectSize*xR/yR, 
      m[[i, 2]] + rectSize}]},
   {i, 1, Length[m]}
   ];
```

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: Please, see my second edit.

Comment: By the way, the solution with `ListPlot` is extremely slow when the data are huge (let's say 100000 elements).

Answer (score 5):

First let's simplify your code so it will be easier to make the adjustment you are asking for.

```
m = {{0.658254, 1.04273, 0.15, 0.613587, 2}, {0.157981, 4.03653, 1.25,
     0.437706, 1}, {0.149204, 1.65371, 2.72, 0.571777, 1}, {0.495885, 
     3.62412, 1.67, 0.00119993, 3}, {-0.149204, 2.23414, 200., 
     0.260858, 0}, {-0.50905, 2.98259, 200., 0.146681, 0}, {-0.662643, 
     1.60788, 21.77, 0.0305032, 1}, {0.539769, 0.385922, 0.33, 
     0.450807, 2}, {0.157981, 3.77687, 1.04, 0.584416, 1}, {-0.623147, 
     4.32675, 200., 0.173352, 0}};

colors = <|-1 -> White, 0 -> Blue, 1 -> Red, 2 -> Darker[Green], 3 -> Cyan|>;
pts = {colors[#[[5]]], AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ m;
```

[image: pts]

Now, let's replace `pts` with a marker generating function that will accept any graphics object and make markers scaled to a specified fraction of the graphics viewport.

```
markers[graphic_, scale_, data_] := 
  Inset[
    Graphics[{colors[#[[5]]], graphic}], 
    #[[1 ;; 2]], {.5, .5}, Scaled[scale]]& 
  /@ data
```

Now we can reproduce your point image with

```
Graphics[markers[Disk[], .07, m]]
```

and also produce square markers this way

```
Graphics[markers[Rectangle[], .08, m]]
```

or this way

```
Graphics[markers[RegularPolygon[4], .08, m]]
```

[image: sqrs]

and even have pentagon markers.

```
Graphics[markers[RegularPolygon[5], .1, m]]
```

[image: penta]

#### Update

Versions of *Mathematica* too old to have associations can use a list of rules to set the colors.

```
colorRules = {-1 -> White, 0 -> Blue, 1 -> Red, 2 -> Darker[Green], 3 -> Cyan};
markers[graphic_, scale_, data_] :=
  Inset[
    Graphics[{#[[5]] /. colorRules, graphic}], 
    #[[1 ;; 2]], {.5, .5}, Scaled[scale]]& 
  /@ data
```

#### Update 2

You only need to make some minor adjustments. Reduce the marker scale factor, add `PlotRangePadding` and remove `PlotRangeClipping`.

```
Show[Graphics[markers[RegularPolygon[4], .025, m]], 
  Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  RotateLabel -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRangePadding -> .15, 
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: show]

Comment: When I copy paste your code I get an error in colors regarding < |. I use v9.0.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z. What error? I don't have V9, so I can not test with it. Please report what error you are getting.

Comment: Since @Vaggelis is on version 9, he won't have `Association[]` available. He can do something like `#[[5]] /. {-1 -> White, 0 -> Blue, 1 -> Red, 2 -> Darker[Green], 3 -> Cyan}` tho.

Comment: @m_goldberg I get the following: `Syntax::tsntxi: "colors=<|-1->White,0->Blue,1->Red,2->Darker[Green],3->Cyan|>;" is incomplete; more input is needed.`, while the < | and | > at the beginning and at the end of the expression are highlighted.

Comment: @J.M. That's too bad, because an association is very suited to his problem. I'll write a version using rules and update.

Comment: @m_goldberg If I include the `Graphics` in a `Show` nasty things happen. See my edit. Moreover, what do you define as `data`?

Comment: About the "nasty things" - see my edit in my answer.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z. The markers do not become distorted when I evaluate your `Show` expression in V.10.3.1

Comment: @m_goldbergThe same happened with my code, but when I closed everything and tried again, they became distorted.

Comment: @m_goldberg What do you define as `data`?

Comment: @Please, see Edit 2.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z. See my 2nd update.

Comment: @m_goldberg Unfortunately, `RegularPolygon` is not recognized in v9.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z. Use `Rectangle[]`